# A PHP calculator which updates in the same place

Tags: php, javascript, calculator

I was initially going to create a classic "updates while you type" Javascript based pension pot calculator but did not want the user to be able to see the business logic by downloading the .js file. However, there does not appear to be a robust way of protecting the business logic in the .js file.

Therefore, I am now going to put the calculation logic on the server in PHP. There is plenty of material out there with respect to creating a form which is submitted to another page that lists the outputs. However, my calculator is a side bar on the home page and I would like to user to click "calculate" and for the results to be displayed in the same box without being taken to a separate page.

Is this feasible and if so what would you suggest as the architecture of the solution? (e.g. keep calculation logic in .php and still call it via Javascript using xyz etc). Looking for guidance and design recommendations. The aim is a calculator with reasonably complex logic but no database lookups and most importantly the user must not be moved to a separate page.

Many thanks.
3rd August 2012

EDIT (17th December 2012): So four months later and I finally cracked it! Have a look at www.pencalc.org which demos what I was trying to build. Uses Javascript to asynchronously call a PHP based calculation. Thank you guys for all your help.

Comment: You say you don't want to use AJAX but what you describe is... AJAX.

Comment: Send the complete form with AJAX and let your PHP script return the result. Inject as HTML element. done.

Comment: @sachlee: Yes, the ideal is AJAX but because I can't protect the .js file from being disclosed I don't mind if the user has to click a button instead and wait a second for the result. By AJAX what I mean to say is the "results update as you type the inputs" dynamism.

Comment: Get over it. You pension pot calculator business logic is not rocket science. Most would-be copycats would sooner code their own from scratch before trying to rip off your js code.

Comment: @knittle: I don't fully understand the suggestion. How would the php code be called in a javascript function and do you have a dummy example implementing the "HTML element injection"?

Comment: @Asaph: LOL. Yes absolutely, it's not some "genius" being protected. It's just that there are a number of way to do the projection and I wish to protect my client, who simply want to give an indication of what one's pension pot might be but not open themselves up to litigation around the underlying assumptions used.

Comment: @TylerDurden AJAX does not mean "update as you type" it's simply an asynchronous request. You can do that on a keypress or a button click. Same thing.

Comment: @Tyler what you've just described *is* AJAX (basically, sending data from JavaScript to the server and back). I'd recommend looking into jQuery (a JavaScript library) and its AJAX functions. They're really easy to use, especially with PHP. http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Comment: @sachleen: Clearly, the word is creating confusion so I've edited it out of the question.

Comment: @TylerDurden That doesn't make sense. Presumably, there are documented rules about the way the pension works and these rules are disclosed to the beneficiaries. The clients should already know how to calculate their pensions manually if they wanted to. They would just use your tool for convenience.

Comment: @Asaph: Things are getting a little side-tracked here. I need help with solving the specific programming problem outlined more so than the rationale. This programming problem is itself useful for others in applications such as tax calculators, quotation estimate calculators, etc where the business would not like to disclose the calculation logic yet provide results reasonably dynamically.

Comment: @TylerDurden I guess my point then is that the best solution to your specific problem is to stick with the client side js file. It will make your app fast and simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

knittl and sachleen were pushing you in the right direction, but I feel like a more complete answer is needed.

If you don't want to expose your business logic to your end-users, you can just use js/AJAX to  automatically submit the form to a PHP script.  The script then computes some value for the calculator, and then only prints the value (say, $20.45).  You JS will eventually see the response from the PHP script.  Once you have the value from the server, dump that value into the relevant field in the calculator.  Now all the user can see is a bunch of JS which posts the user's data to a PHP script.

However, I would have a look at [JQuery](http://jquery.com/), which helps in automating a lot of the work of AJAX and anything that involves manipulating the DOM.

Comment: Oh wonderful! I didn't realise the Javascript and PHP live interaction was possible.

Comment: If your problem has been solved you should accept whatever answer was correct.  For others who may have a similar problem and stumble upon your post it will help them to identify the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with no business logic in your JavaScript:

1. Save the content of every user action with [jQuery .data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) or
   something similar
2. Send this data via AJAX to a PHP script when the user clicks Calculate
3. The PHP processes the request and outputs a result.
4. The javascript places the result back into the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Your business logic will be in your PHP page. It will take inputs from the `$_POST` array and process the data, and echo an output.

Take a look at jQuery's [`.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) on how to make POST requests. You make a request with the inputs and you get the output from the PHP. Then you can display the data using [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) or [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) or something similar.